# Custom font rendering problems

Tags: html, css, font-face, custom-font

So I sometimes want to emphasize certain words like this:

```
<h1>I want to <span class="emphasis">emphasize</span> some text.</h1>
```

At the same time, I would like to use a custom font for h1 text:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'MuseoSlab';
    src: url('https://digital_time_capsules.s3.amazonaws.com/fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.eot');
    src: url('https://digital_time_capsules.s3.amazonaws.com/fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"), url('https://digital_time_capsules.s3.amazonaws.com/fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.svg#MuseoSlab500Regular') format("svg"), url('https://digital_time_capsules.s3.amazonaws.com/fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.woff') format("woff"), url('https://digital_time_capsules.s3.amazonaws.com/fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.ttf') format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

[Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/PMqX9/)

Problem is, Chrome in Windows overlaps the span text:

[image: chrome overlap]

Firefox and IE don't seem to render the font smoothly:

[image: looks jagged]

Opera seems to render it just the way I want:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's going on, and how I can fix these problems?

**EDIT**:

Sometimes I have that egregious problem in Chrome; sometimes I don't. And I have the latest Chrome installed, too:

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly in Chrome latest: http://i.imgur.com/Hf2MONa.png

Comment: Not an answer, but @ your screens 2 and 3: Don't expect fonts (even not system fonts) to render the same in all agents (browser, OS, device, ...).

Comment: @DannyBeckett Weird, I just opened the JSFiddle link again, and that phenomenon is gone. I didn't even update my Chrome...

Comment: @DannyBeckett it's back again for me, on chrome. No idea why the problem comes and goes. Restarting Chrome doesn't help, either.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why Firefox and IE show the font the way they do is that `h1` element has `font-weight: bold` by default, and you are declaring the font as `normal` weight. What this browsers do is arguably the correct move: in lack of a bold typeface, they algorithmically bold the letters.

To avoid that, add `h1 { font-weight: normal; }`. Alternatively, use a bold typeface of the font family.

The odd overlap in your Chrome sounds like an installation-specific problem, so you should first consider updating or re-installing Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the Firefox and IE rendering! And as for Chrome, weirdly my friend on his laptop experienced the same effect, so I am concerned that this may be a somewhat widespread problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had once exactly the same issue with Chrome. It appears to be related to the rendering of SVG fonts in Chrome. If you change the order of the font files in the `@font-face` so that the SVG is at the end of the list, the issue disappears. Your example on jsfiddle still renders incorrect in the current version of Chrome (29.0.1547.76), so the render bug is still present.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone in the future, but I was able to correct this issue by following the solution in the following question: [Chrome svg-Font-Rendering breaks Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674808/chrome-svg-font-rendering-breaks-layout/14345363)

This successfully fixed the non-smooth edges without breaking the layout and/or squishing the fonts.