# Chrome Google Fonts rendering

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, rendering

Does anyone know about the current situation with Google Fonts rendering in Chrome? I've read through tonnes of posts and outdated solutions that no longer work, and it seems that the latest best solution is to use Font Squirrel to get the Google Font and then link the SVG format first so that Chrome uses it. But apparently SVG font rendering is glitchy/inconsistent/unreliable in other ways. Is there a good alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only fix seems to be reordering SVG in the `@font-face` CSS code, which you mentioned. The 'glitching' you're referring to seems to be fixable by using a media query trick outlined in the following post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14345363/1490006

Answer (score 0):

When you use google fonts, use property font-weight in your CSS. I had this problem with font rendering on my chrome browser. After I have setup this property problem has gone.