# How can I create a CSS sliding menu?

Tags: html, css

I attempted to create a hamburger menu similar to this:

[image]

Reference: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveRetinaReadyMenu/

However for some reason here's what I got:

[image]

Here's my CSS:

```
/*= ICON BOXES
--------------------------------------------------------*/

ul.icon-menu {margin-top:29px;}
li.icon-box {width: 120px; height: 120px; list-style: none; left: -47px; position: relative; margin-bottom: 3px;}
li.icon-box.home {background: #e74c3c;}
li.icon-box.aboutme {background: #1dd0ad;}
li.icon-box.portfolio {background: #3498db;}
li.icon-box.blog {background: #f1c40f;}
li.icon-box.contact {background: #f39c12;}
.icon-box h2{Museo500-Regular; font-size: 20px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);}

.icon-box a {display: block;}
i.fa {
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  color:white ;
  margin:20px 0 0 20px
}


/*= TITLE BOXES
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.icon-box.home h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #E74C3C; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
        border-left: 3px solid #a7382d;

}

.icon-box.home a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

.icon-box.aboutme h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #1dd0ad; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #0d866e;
}

.icon-box.aboutme a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}


.icon-box.portfolio h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #3498db; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #2177b1;
}

.icon-box.portfolio a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}


.icon-box.blog h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #f1c40f; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #b8960e;
}

.icon-box.blog a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

.icon-box.contact h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #f39c12; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #bc780d;
}

.icon-box.contact a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}



/*= MENU ICONS
--------------------------------------------------------*/


span.icon { display: inline-block; background: url('../img/icon-sprites.png')no-repeat;  width: 32px; height: 32px; margin: 43px 40px;}
span.icon.home { background-position: 0px 0px;}
span.icon.aboutme { background-position: -36px 0px;}
span.icon.portfolio { background-position: -72px 0px;}
span.icon.blog { background-position: -109px 0px;}
span.icon.contact { background-position: -145px 0px;}

.icon-box a {
    padding: 120px;
}

.icon-menu i {
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px transparent;
    padding: 0.2em 0.25em;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
        transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
    }

.icon-menu li:hover i,
.icon-menu li:active i,
.icon-menu li:focus i {     
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
        -webkit-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Which doesn't look good. I want it to be perfectly like that link hamburger menu with the same size. How can I perfect my hamburger menu here?

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/xfq0eLhu/1/

Any idea what should I work on? Please help! I'm stuck!

Comment: What are your concerns? The fiddle looks like it works

Comment: Look at this image. http://prntscr.com/bezll4 it goes up instead of hide and there is dark gray background on it. sucks!

Comment: when you click the burger icon it must hide menus similar to this: http://prntscr.com/bezm67

Comment: Here's a good reference of the hamburger menu: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveRetinaReadyMenu/

Answer (score 0):

Try  this it may help you

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300");
@font-face
{
 font-family: Museo500-Regular;
 src: url('../fonts/Museo500-Regular.otf');
}


body {background: #f9f9f9; font-family: Museo500-Regular;}

a{ text-decoration: none; }
h2 {  color: #fff; font-size: 22px; margin: 0 24px;}


/*= ICON BOXES
--------------------------------------------------------*/

ul.icon-menu {margin-top:29px;}
li.icon-box {width: 120px; height: 120px; list-style: none; left: -47px; position: relative; margin-bottom: 3px;}
li.icon-box.home {background: #e74c3c;}
li.icon-box.aboutme {background: #1dd0ad;}
li.icon-box.portfolio {background: #3498db;}
li.icon-box.blog {background: #f1c40f;}
li.icon-box.contact {background: #f39c12;}
.icon-box h2{Museo500-Regular; font-size: 20px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);}

/*.icon-box a {display: block;}*/
i.fa {
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  color:white ;
  margin:20px 0 0 20px;
 margin-top: 17px;
    margin-left: -42px !important;
}

.fa {
 margin-left: -44px ;
    margin-top: 15px ;
}


/*= TITLE BOXES
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.icon-box.home h2 { 
  z-index: -999;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  opacity: 0; 
  background: #E74C3C; 
  line-height: 120px; 
  width: 120px; 
  -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
 -moz-transition: all .5s;
 -ms-transition: all .5s;
 -o-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
  border-left: 3px solid #a7382d;
  
}

.icon-box.home a:hover h2 { 
 opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 
}

.icon-box.aboutme h2 { 
  z-index: -999;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  opacity: 0; 
  background: #1dd0ad; 
  line-height: 120px; 
  width: 120px; 
  -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
 -moz-transition: all .5s;
 -ms-transition: all .5s;
 -o-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #0d866e;
}

.icon-box.aboutme a:hover h2 { 
 opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 
}


.icon-box.portfolio h2 { 
  z-index: -999;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  opacity: 0; 
  background: #3498db; 
  line-height: 120px; 
  width: 120px; 
  -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
 -moz-transition: all .5s;
 -ms-transition: all .5s;
 -o-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
 border-left: 3px solid #2177b1;
}

.icon-box.portfolio a:hover h2 { 
 opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
  
}


.icon-box.blog h2 { 
  z-index: -999;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  opacity: 0; 
  background: #f1c40f; 
  line-height: 120px; 
  width: 120px; 
  -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
 -moz-transition: all .5s;
 -ms-transition: all .5s;
 -o-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
 border-left: 3px solid #b8960e;
}

.icon-box.blog a:hover h2 { 
 opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
  
}

.icon-box.contact h2 { 
  z-index: -999;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  opacity: 0; 
  background: #f39c12; 
  line-height: 120px; 
  width: 120px; 
  -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
 -moz-transition: all .5s;
 -ms-transition: all .5s;
 -o-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
 border-left: 3px solid #bc780d;
}

.icon-box.contact a:hover h2 { 
 opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
  
}



/*= MENU ICONS
--------------------------------------------------------*/


span.icon { display: inline-block; background: url('../img/icon-sprites.png')no-repeat;  width: 32px; height: 32px; margin: 43px 40px;}
span.icon.home { background-position: 0px 0px;}
span.icon.aboutme { background-position: -36px 0px;}
span.icon.portfolio { background-position: -72px 0px;}
span.icon.blog { background-position: -109px 0px;}
span.icon.contact { background-position: -145px 0px;}

.icon-box a {
    padding: 0 60px;
}
.icon-box:hover a {
    padding: 120px;
}

.icon-menu i {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px transparent;
    padding: 0.2em 0.25em;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
 }

.icon-menu li:hover i,
.icon-menu li:active i,
.icon-menu li:focus i {  
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
}


header{position: relative;}

nav ul{
 display: block; 
 flex-wrap: wrap; 
 /*max-width: 1080px; */
 margin: 0 auto;  
  /* background: #999;*/
}
nav ul,
nav li{
 flex: 1; 
}
nav li:last-child{border-bottom: none;}
nav a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
 display: block;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
}
nav a:hover{
 /*background: #adacac;*/
 color: #fff;
}
nav li{
 position: relative;
 line-height: 50px;
 /*color: #fff;*/
 text-align: center;
}  
nav label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 20px;
    transition: .4s;
}
nav input,
nav label{
 display: none;
 width: 36px; 
 height: 36px; 
 /*background: #555; */
 color: #fff; 
 text-align: center; 
 line-height: 36px;
 font-size: 1.6rem;
 border-radius: 4px;
} 
nav label{position: absolute; top: 8px; right: 8px; transition: .4s;}
nav label:hover{cursor:pointer;}
nav label:before{
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 font-size: 24px;
 content: "\f0c9";
 text-align: center;
}

.nav .navtoogle {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.8em;
    font-family: 'Lato',Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: rgb(7, 16, 15);
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 32.438em)
.nav .navtoogle {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
 nav ul{
  transform: translateY(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0, .7);
      transition: all .5s;
   display: block;
    padding-top: 56px;
 }
 nav li{
  flex: none; 
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #777;
 } 
 nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul{
  transform: translateY(-150%);
  width: 100%;
  background: #999;   
      transition: all .5s;
 }
 nav label{display: block;}  
 nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul li:nth-child(1){
  background: #777; 
  color: #fff;
 }  
}

/***************** FONTS ********************/
@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300");
html{font-size: 62.5%; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
body{font-size: 1.6rem; min-height: 100vh;}
header{position: relative;}
main{padding: 2rem;}

/***************** NAVIGATION ********************/
nav li:last-child{border-bottom: none;}
nav input,
nav label{
 display: none;
 width: 36px; 
 height: 36px; 
 background: #555; 
 color: #fff; 
 text-align: center; 
 line-height: 36px;
 font-size: 1.6rem;
 border-radius: 4px;
} 
nav label{position: absolute; top: 8px; right: 8px; transition: .4s;}
nav label:hover{cursor:pointer;}
nav label:before{
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 font-size: 24px;
 content: "\f0c9";
 text-align: center;
}

.mobile {
     display: none;
}


/*************** MEDIA QUERIES *******************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){

 ul.icon-menu
 {     margin-top: 15% !IMPORTANT; }
 
 nav li {text-align: left !IMPORTANT;}
li.icon-box
{
 width: 75% !Important;
 height: 40px !Important; margin-left:10%;
 
}
li.icon-box .fa { margin-left:20px !important;
    margin-top: 5px !important;}

.mobile {
     display: inline;
 padding : 0px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
     color: #fff;
    font-weight: 200;
 line-height: 32px;
}

li.icon-box {
 margin-bottom: 0px !important;
     border: none;
}
 
 .fa-4x {
    font-size: 1.3em !IMPORTANT;
}

.icon-box a:hover h2.nomobile { 
display: none !IMPORTANT; 
}

.icon-box a:hover h2.mobile { 
display: block !IMPORTANT; 
}
 nav ul{
  transform: translateY(0);
  box-shadow: none !IMPORTANT;
      transition: all .5s;
 }
 nav li{
  flex: none;
  line-height:40px !IMPORTANT;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #777;
 } 

 nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul{
  
  width: 100%;
  background: #999;   
      transition: all .5s;
 }
 nav label{display: block;     color: #000 !IMPORTANT; margin-left: 5%;
    background: transparent;     margin-top: 15%;}  
 nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul li:nth-child(1){
  background: #777; 
  color: #fff;
 }  
}
    </style>

  </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
   <nav>
         <input type="checkbox" id="css-toggle-menu" name="css-toggle-menu"> 
         <ul class="main icon-menu">
   <li class="icon-box home"> 
    <i class="fa fa-home fa-4x"></i><a href="#" class="mobile"><h1 class="mobile">Home</h1></a>
    <a href="#">
          <h2 class="nomobile">Home</h2>
       
    </a>
   </li> 
   
   <li class="icon-box aboutme"> 
    <i class="fa fa-home fa-4x"></i><a href="#" class="mobile"><h1 class="mobile">About Me</h1></a>
        <a href="#">
          <h2 class="nomobile">About Me</h2>
       </a>
    </li>
    
    
    <li class="icon-box portfolio"> 
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-4x"></i> <a href="#" class="mobile"><h1 class="mobile">Portfolio</h1></a>
         <a href="#">
             <h2 class="nomobile">Portfolio</h2>
         </a>
    </li>
    
    
       <li class="icon-box blog"> 
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-4x"></i><a href="#" class="mobile"><h1 class="mobile">Blog</h1></a>
            <a href="#">
              <h2 class="nomobile">Blog</h2>
         </a>
    </li>
    
    
       <li class="icon-box contact"> 
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-4x"></i><a href="#" class="mobile"><h1 class="mobile">Contact</h1></a>
            <a href="#">
      <h2 class="nomobile">Contact</h2>
           </a>
    </li>

    
         </ul> 
         <label for="css-toggle-menu" id="css-toggle-menu"></label> 
   </nav>
</div>
   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: still the same mate.

Answer (score -1):

try this

**css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src: url('../fonts/icomoon.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* Windows Chrome ugly fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674808/chrome-svg-font-rendering-breaks-layout/14345363#14345363 */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'icomoon';
        src: url('../fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
    };
}

.icon-team, .icon-blog, .icon-home, .icon-portfolio, .icon-services, .icon-contact, .icon-menu {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.icon-team:before {
    content: "\e000";
}

.icon-blog:before {
    content: "\e001";
}

.icon-home:before {
    content: "\e002";
}

.icon-portfolio:before {
    content: "\e003";
}

.icon-services:before {
    content: "\e004";
}

.icon-contact:before {
    content: "\e005";
}

.icon-menu:before {
    content: "\f0c9";
}

a, li {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}


/* Global CSS that are applied for all screen sizes */

.nav ul {
    max-width: 1240px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.nav li span {
    display: block;
}

.nav a {
    display: block;
    color: rgba(249, 249, 249, .9);
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: color .5s, background .5s, height .5s;
    -moz-transition: color .5s, background .5s, height .5s;
    -o-transition: color .5s, background .5s, height .5s;
    -ms-transition: color .5s, background .5s, height .5s;
    transition: color .5s, background .5s, height .5s;
}

.nav i{
    /* Make the font smoother for Chrome */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

/* Remove the blue Webkit background when element is tapped */

a, button {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

/* Hover effect for the whole navigation to make the hovered item stand out */

.no-touch .nav ul:hover a {
    color: rgba(249, 249, 249, .5);
}

.no-touch .nav ul:hover a:hover {
    color: rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.99);
}

/* Adding some background color to the different menu items */

.nav li:nth-child(6n+1) {
    background: rgb(208, 101, 3);
}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+2) {
    background: rgb(233, 147, 26);
}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+3) {
    background: rgb(22, 145, 190);
}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+4) {
    background: rgb(22, 107, 162);
}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+5) {
    background: rgb(27, 54, 71);
}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+6) {
    background: rgb(21, 40, 54);
}

/* For screen bigger than 800px */
@media (min-width: 50em) {

    /* Transforms the list into a horizontal navigation */
    .nav li {
        float: left;
        width: 16.66666666666667%;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-transition: border .5s;
        -moz-transition: border .5s;
        -o-transition: border .5s;
        -ms-transition: border .5s;
        transition: border .5s;
    }

    .nav a {
        display: block;
        width: auto;
    }

    /* hover, focused and active effects that add a little colored border to the different items */
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+1) a:hover,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+1) a:active,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+1) a:focus {
        border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(174, 78, 1);
    }

    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+2) a:hover,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+2) a:active,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+2) a:focus {
        border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(191, 117, 20);
    }

    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+3) a:hover,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+3) a:active,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+3) a:focus {
        border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(12, 110, 149);
    }

    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+4) a:hover,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+4) a:active,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+4) a:focus {
        border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(10, 75, 117);
    }

    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+5) a:hover,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+5) a:active,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+5) a:focus {
        border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(16, 34, 44);
    }

    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+6) a:hover,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+6) a:active,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+6) a:focus {
        border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(9, 18, 25);
    }

    /* Placing the icon */

    .icon {
        padding-top: 1.4em;
    }

    .icon + span {
        margin-top: 2.1em;
        -webkit-transition: margin .5s;
        -moz-transition: margin .5s;
        -o-transition: margin .5s;
        -ms-transition: margin .5s;
        transition: margin .5s;
    }

    /* Animating the height of the element*/
    .nav a {
        height: 9em;
    }

    .no-touch .nav a:hover ,
    .nav a:active ,
    .nav a:focus {
        height: 10em;
    }   

    /* Making the text follow the height animation */
    .no-touch .nav a:hover .icon + span {
        margin-top: 3.2em;
        -webkit-transition: margin .5s;
        -moz-transition: margin .5s;
        -o-transition: margin .5s;
        -ms-transition: margin .5s;
        transition: margin .5s;
    }

    /* Positioning the icons and preparing for the animation*/
    .nav i {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0.4em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: 1.8em;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px transparent;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
        transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
    }   

    /* Animate the box-shadow to create the effect */
    .no-touch .nav a:hover i,
    .no-touch .nav a:active i,
    .no-touch .nav a:focus i {      
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
        -webkit-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
        transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 50em) and (max-width: 61.250em) {

    /* Size and font adjustments to make it fit into the screen*/
    .nav ul {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

}

/* The "tablet" and "mobile" version */

@media (max-width: 49.938em) {      

    /* Instead of adding a border, we transition the background color */
    .no-touch .nav ul li:nth-child(6n+1) a:hover,
    .no-touch .nav ul li:nth-child(6n+1) a:active,
    .no-touch .nav ul li:nth-child(6n+1) a:focus {
        background: rgb(227, 119, 20);
    }

    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+2) a:hover,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+2) a:active,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+2) a:focus {
        background: rgb(245, 160, 41);
    }

    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+3) a:hover,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+3) a:active,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+3) a:focus {
        background: rgb(44, 168, 219);
    }

    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+4) a:hover,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+4) a:active,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+4) a:focus {
        background: rgb(31, 120, 176);
    }

    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+5) a:hover,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+5) a:active,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+5) a:focus {
        background: rgb(39, 70, 90);
    }

    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+6) a:hover,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+6) a:active,
    .no-touch .nav li:nth-child(6n+6) a:focus {
        background: rgb(32, 54, 68);
    }

    .nav ul li {
        -webkit-transition: background 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: background 0.5s;
        -o-transition: background 0.5s;
        -ms-transition: background 0.5s;
        transition: background 0.5s;
    }   

}

/* CSS specific to the 2x3 columns version */
@media (min-width:32.5em) and (max-width: 49.938em) {

    /* Creating the 2 column layout using floating elements once again */
    .nav li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }

    /* Adding some padding to make the elements look nicer*/
    .nav a {
        padding: 0.8em;     
    }

    /* Displaying the icons on the left, and the text on the right side using inlin-block*/
    .nav li span, 
    .nav li span.icon {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .nav li span.icon {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .nav li .icon + span {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .icon + span {
        position: relative;
        top: -0.2em;
    }

    /* Adaptating to the icons to animate the size and border of the rounded background in a more discreet way */
    .nav li i {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8% 9%;
        border: 4px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        -webkit-transition: border .5s;
        -moz-transition: border .5s;
        -o-transition: border .5s;
        -ms-transition: border .5s;
        transition: border .5s;
    }

    /* Transition effect on the border color */
    .no-touch .nav li:hover i,
    .no-touch .nav li:active i,
    .no-touch .nav li:focus i {
        border: 4px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }

}

/* Adapting the font size and width for smaller screns*/
@media (min-width: 32.5em) and (max-width: 38.688em) {

    .nav li span.icon {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .nav li .icon + span {
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }
}

/* Styling the toggle menu link and hiding it */
.nav .navtoogle{
    display: none;  
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.8em;
    font-family: 'Lato',Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: rgb(7, 16, 15);
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background: none;   
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navtoogle i{
    z-index:-1;
}

.icon-menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 1.6em;
}

@media (max-width: 32.438em) {

    /* Unhiding the styled menu link */
    .nav .navtoogle{
        margin: 0;
        display: block;
    }

    /* Animating the height of the navigation when the button is clicked */

    /* When JavaScript is disabled, we hide the menu */
    .no-js .nav ul {
        max-height: 30em;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* When JavaScript is enabled, we hide the menu */
    .js .nav ul {
        max-height: 0em;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* Displaying the menu when the user has clicked on the button*/
    .js .nav .active + ul {     
        max-height: 30em;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: max-height .4s;
        -moz-transition: max-height .4s;
        -o-transition: max-height .4s;
        -ms-transition: max-height .4s;
        transition: max-height .4s;
    }

    /* Adapting the layout of the menu for smaller screens : icon on the left and text on the right*/

    .nav li span {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .nav a {
        padding: 0.5em;     
    }

    .icon + span {
        margin-left: 1em;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }

    /* Adding a left border of 8 px with a different color for each menu item*/
    .nav li:nth-child(6n+1) {
        border-left: 8px solid rgb(174, 78, 1);
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(6n+2) {
        border-left: 8px solid rgb(191, 117, 20);
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(6n+3) {
        border-left: 8px solid rgb(13, 111, 150);
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(6n+4) {
        border-left: 8px solid rgb(10, 75, 117);
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(6n+5) {
        border-left: 8px solid rgb(16, 34, 44);
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(6n+6) {
        border-left: 8px solid rgb(9, 18, 25);
    }

    /* make the nav bigger on touch screens */
    .touch .nav a {
        padding: 0.8em;
    }
}

/* General Demo Style */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);

@font-face {
    font-family: 'codropsicons';
    src:url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.svg#codropsicons') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

*, *:after, *:before { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
body, html { font-size: 15px; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

/* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

body {
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #89867e;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.main,
.container > header {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2em;
}

.main {
    max-width: 82.667em;
    min-height: 40em;
}

.container > header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4em 2em 3em;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
}

.container > header h1 {
    font-size: 2.625em;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.container > header span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 60%;
    color: #ceccc6;
    padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
}

/* Header Style */
.codrops-top {
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    line-height: 2.2;
}

.codrops-top a {
    padding: 0 1em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    color: #888;
    display: inline-block;
}

.codrops-top a:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.codrops-top span.right {
    float: right;
}

.codrops-top span.right a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.codrops-icon:before {
    font-family: 'codropsicons';
    margin: 0 4px;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.codrops-icon-drop:before {
    content: "\e001";
}
.codrops-icon-prev:before {
    content: "\e004";
}
.codrops-icon-archive:before {
    content: "\e002";
}
.codrops-icon-next:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
.codrops-icon-about:before {
    content: "\e003";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 25em) { 
    .codrops-icon span {
        display: none;
    }
    .container > header {
        font-size: 75%;
    }
}
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/od6qqar7/)**

Comment: Say what? you did not fix my issue. You just copied the example on the example site I sent you. Are you kiddin me? Please don't I really want to know what going on w/ my codes and fix this: http://prntscr.com/bezll4